# Composer Magento 2 - can't install dev-master

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I want to run composer install and use modules with stability flag dev-master.
But composer won't install them.
What can I do to install these modules?

I use this command:

```
composer install --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

The result is that only modules with a version will be installed like:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "company/magento2-mymodule-name": "dev-master",
    "company/magento2-mytheme-name": "dev-master",
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have already file `composer.lock` created? If so, try running `composer update`.